# Define a promise creating a new Service Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, service, promise

I have a question about the promise system in AngularJS and the creation of services. I have a service called Customer:

```
angular.module("app").factory("Customer", ["CustomerDBServices", "OfficesList", "$q",
    function(CustomerDBServices, OfficesList, $q){
        return function(customerID){

            var self = this;

            //attributes
            this.name = null;
            this.ID = null;
            this.code = null;
            this.isVisible = 1;
            this.showOffices = true;
            this.offices = new OfficesList();

            //constructor
            if(typeof customerID !== "undefined"){
                var metacustomer = CustomerDBServices.find({ID:customerID}, function(){
                    self.name = metacustomer.results.customer_name;
                    self.ID = metacustomer.results.customer_ID;
                    self.code = metacustomer.results.customer_internal_code;
                    self.isVisible = metacustomer.results.customer_is_visible;
                    self.getOffices();
                });
            }

            //add office to customer
            this.addNewOffice = function(){
                self.offices.addNewOffice();
            };

            //remove office from customer
            this.removeOffice = function(officeIndex){
                self.offices.removeOffice(officeIndex);
            };

            //show offices
            this.toggleOfficeVisibility = function(officeIndex){
                self.offices.toggleOfficeVisibility(officeIndex);
            };
}]);
```

In the "constructor" part of this service there is an AJAX call to a service that loads the attributes of the customer from the database. This is an async task. How can I create a promise in this situation? I use the customer service like this:

```
var customer = new Customer(ID);
```

and I would like to do something like

```
var customer = new Customer(ID).then(
        function(){...}, //success
        function(){...} //error
);
```

To do this I need a promise. Do I have to program a method `create()` within the customer service?

```
angular.module("app").factory("Customer", ["CustomerDBServices", "OfficesList", "$q",
    function(CustomerDBServices, OfficesList, $q){
        return function(customerID){

            var self = this;

            //attributes
            this.name = null;
            this.ID = null;
            this.code = null;
            this.isVisible = 1;
            this.showOffices = true;
            this.offices = new OfficesList();

            //costructor
            this.create = function(){
                if(typeof customerID !== "undefined"){
                    var rest = $q.defer();
                    var metacustomer = CustomerDBServices.find({ID:customerID}, function(){
                        self.name = metacustomer.results.customer_name;
                        self.ID = metacustomer.results.customer_ID;
                        self.code = metacustomer.results.customer_internal_code;
                        self.isVisible = metacustomer.results.customer_is_visible;
                        self.getOffices();

                        rest.resolve("ok!");
                    });
                    return rest.promise;
                }
            }

            ...
            ...
            ...
}]);
```

and then use that stuff like this?

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.create(ID).then(
    function(){...},
    function(){...},
)
```

Isn't there a way to call the "new Customer" and receive a promise? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I strongly recommend against this. Don't put complex asynchronous logic in a constructor it's very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So do you suggest to create a method "retrieveCustomer" in witch put the async creation stuff?

Comment: Yes, I'll also add an answer with how you _can_ accomplish this and a note that you probably shouldn't. I'd also promisify the `CustomerDBServices` service if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment I recommend against this approach. Putting complex asynchronous logic in a constructor is usually confusing and does not make for a very good or clear API.

That said, You don't need a `.create` method.

The trick is: If a function called as a constructor returns an object in JavaScript - it is returned instead of the `this` value.

Sparing you the whole Angular around it:

```
function(CustomerDBServices, OfficesList, $q){
    return function(customerID){

        var p = $q.defer();
        var that = p.promise; // our 'that' is now a promise

        //attributes
        that.name = null;
        that.ID = null;
        that.code = null;
        that.isVisible = 1;
        that.showOffices = true;
        that.offices = new OfficesList();
        // use `that` instead of this in additional code

        if(typeof customerID !== "undefined"){
            var metacustomer = CustomerDBServices.find({ID:customerID}, function(){
                self.name = metacustomer.results.customer_name;
                self.ID = metacustomer.results.customer_ID;
                self.code = metacustomer.results.customer_internal_code;
                self.isVisible = metacustomer.results.customer_is_visible;
                self.getOffices();
                that.resolve("ok!");
           });
       }
        return that; // we return the promise here.
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but I've just realized that doing this the call "new Customer()" returns a promise (course, it is what I wanted!), so how can I access to the customer then? :-/

Comment: Ops, sorry! I haven't seen that you have assigned the property directly to "that" like "that.ID" or "that.name". Ok, it's clear :)